# Build failure due to package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain does not exist

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, package

Error on `mvn clean install` of the component -

```
[INFO] 6 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.001 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-28T17:30:25+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project project-component: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/sandeepan.nath/Desktop/codebase/path/to/project/component/src/main/java/com/path/to/JPAConfigurationMysql.java:[11,53] package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sandeepan.nath/Desktop/codebase/path/to/project/component/src/main/java/com/path/to/JPAConfigurationMysql.java:[12,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
[ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa
```

The class where I am getting the error has this import -

```
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
```

Output of `mvn dependency:tree` of the component I am trying to build gives this -

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.3.RELEASE:compile
```

I checked that the jar is already present in -

```
repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

The component I am trying to run is dependent on another componentn. I checked that the pom of this dependent project has -

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.dependencyproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-project</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And pom of dependency project has following -

```
<properties>
         <spring-boot.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-common.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And several other org.springframework dependendencies defined. 
It seems, some of the dependency definitions are redundant, like `spring-boot-starter` is not needed if `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is set.

However, for the component for which I am having issue, i.e. spring-boot-autoconfigure, I see no chances of conflict as `spring-boot-autoconfigure` is not separately mentioned.

Comment: I do not see any database listed in the dependencies. Could it be that it requires a db to complete auto configuration? Try h2 or MySQL and see.

Comment: You're using Boot 1.5.2 in one spot and 1.2.5 elsewhere; both of these are out of date for 1.x, and if you're putting together a _new_ project you should be using 2.

Comment: What's the JDK version you use?
I suggest to open the project in some good IDE (IntelliJ IDEA e.g.) and see what it tells about the project.

Comment: @KnightRider there is mysql-connector-java defined in the dependency of dependency project.

Comment: @OndraŽižka JDK 1.8.